# A function into another function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function

I have some functions into one big function in JavaScript.
But the code is not working well since I think the problem is about those little functions.
However I need this code to be like the way that I wrote.
(Program ask user some questions and will check the user's answer and it continues asking questions and taking answers from user). The important issue is that the user has a score that should be more than 70 so user can answer these questions. (I asked user some questions already and gave them a score between 0 to 100).

```css
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0) !important;
    text-align: center !important;
}

body {
    background: url('../images/Question page background/background.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif !important;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#overly-behind {
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
    color: white;
    font-size: 130%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 2;
    width: 80%;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

span {
    color: rgb(95, 35, 207);
}

#score-con {
    padding-top: 600px;
}

#start1, #start2 {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* inputs */
.edit {
    width: 200px;
    height: 35px;
    font-size: 80%;
    padding: 12px;
}

#con1, #con2, #con3, #con4, #con5, #con6, #con7, #con8, #main-hard-con, #conh1, #conh2, #conh3, #conh4, #conh5, #conh6 {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Ali Bolouki, Questions"/>
    <meta name="description" content="Ali Bolouki's personal website with questions"/>
    <meta name="author" content="Ali Bolouki"/>
    <!--Title bar-->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../images/title bar/icons8-super-mario-96.png"/>
    <title>Ali Bolouki</title>
    <!--CSS3-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    <!--Bootstrap4-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!--Googel fonts-->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fira+Sans:wght@200;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main-con" class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="overly-behind" class="col-12">
                <p id="p" class="col-12 text-center lead">So I will ask you some personal questions about myself. I guess just two person can answer all questions.</p>
                <p id="start1" class="btn-link lead" onclick="start();">Start</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--1-->
    <div class="container-fluid" id="con1">
        <div clss="row">
            <div id="overly-behind" class="col-12">
                <form action="#" class="col-12" onsubmit="return false;">
                    <label class="col-12 d-block" for="q1">When is my birthday?<br/> <small>Write like this in Persian (dd/mm/yyyy) and this (yyyy/mm/dd) in English</small></label>
                    <input class="col-md-3 col-12 border edit rounded mb-2" type="text" id="q1" placeholder="Type it here"/>
                    <input onclick="question1(q1);" class="col-md-2 col-12 btn btn-dark border rounded" id="q1-sub" type="submit" value="Check"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--2-->
    <div class="container-fluid" id="con2">
        <div clss="row">
            <div id="overly-behind" class="col-12">
                <form action="#" class="col-12" onsubmit="return false;">
                    <label class="col-12 d-block" for="q2">Where do I live?<br/> <small>Write in Persian or English</small></label>
                    <input class="col-md-3 col-12 border edit rounded mb-2" type="text" id="q2" placeholder="Type it here"/>
                    <input onclick="question2(q2);" class="col-md-2 col-12 btn btn-dark border rounded" id="q2-sub" type="submit" value="Check"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--3-->
    <div class="container-fluid" id="con3">
        <div clss="row">
            <div id="overly-behind" class="col-12">
                <form action="#" class="col-12" onsubmit="return false;">
                    <label class="col-12 d-block" for="q3">Which one is my phone? (Type the number)<br/><span><small>1.CATs70&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2.iPhone11&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;3.iPhone8 plus&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;4.BlackBerry prive</small></span></label>
                    <input class="col-md-3 col-12 border edit rounded mb-2" type="text" id="q3" placeholder="Type it here"/>
                    <input onclick="question3(q3);" class="col-md-2 col-12 btn btn-dark border rounded" id="q3-sub" type="submit" value="Check"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--4-->
    <div class="container-fluid" id="con4">
        <div clss="row">
            <div id="overly-behind" class="col-12">
                <form action="#" class="col-12" onsubmit="return false;">
                    <label class="col-12 d-block" for="q4">Which type of music do I like?<br/>
                        <span><small>1.Rap&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2.Pop&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;3.Classic&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;4.Everything</small></span>
                    </label>
                    <input class="col-md-3 col-12 border edit rounded mb-2" type="text" id="q4" placeholder="Type it here"/>
                    <input onclick="question4(q4);" class="col-md-2 col-12 btn btn-dark border rounded" id="q4-sub" type="submit" value="Check"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--5-->
    <div class="container-fluid" id="con5">
        <div clss="row">
            <div id="overly-behind" class="col-12">
                <form action="#" class="col-12" onsubmit="return false;">
                    <label class="col-12 d-block" for="q5">Do I have a dog? (yes or no)</label>
                    <input class="col-md-3 col-12 border edit rounded mb-2" type="text" id="q5" placeholder="Type it here"/>
                    <input onclick="question5(q5);" class="col-md-2 col-12 btn btn-dark border rounded" id="q5-sub" type="submit" value="Check"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--6-->
    <div class="container-fluid" id="con6">
        <div clss="row">
            <div id="overly-behind" class="col-12">
                <form action="#" class="col-12" onsubmit="return false;">
                    <label class="col-12 d-block" for="q6">Do I like motorcycle?</label>
                    <input class="col-md-3 col-12 border edit rounded mb-2" type="text" id="q6" placeholder="Type it here"/>
                    <input onclick="question6(q6);" class="col-md-2 col-12 btn btn-dark border rounded" id="q6-sub" type="submit" value="Check"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--7-->
    <div class="container-fluid" id="con7">
        <div clss="row">
            <div id="overly-behind" class="col-12">
                <form action="#" class="col-12" onsubmit="return false;">
                    <label class="col-12 d-block" for="q7">Which one is my favorite car? <br/>
                        <span><small>1.BMW&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2.Lamborghini&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;3.Mercedes-Benz&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;4.پراید</small></span>
                    </label>
                    <input class="col-md-3 col-12 border edit rounded mb-2" type="text" id="q7" placeholder="Type it here"/>
                    <input onclick="question7(q7);" class="col-md-2 col-12 btn btn-dark border rounded" id="q7-sub" type="submit" value="Check"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--8-->
    <div class="container-fluid" id="con8">
        <div clss="row">
            <div id="overly-behind" class="col-12">
                <form action="#" class="col-12" onsubmit="return false;">
                    <label class="col-12 d-block" for="q8">In my piont of view, which country is special? <br/>
                        <span><small>1.U.K&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2.U.S.A&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;3.Russia&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;4.Iran</small></span>
                    </label>
                    <input class="col-md-3 col-12 border edit rounded mb-2" type="text" id="q8" placeholder="Type it here"/>
                    <input onclick="question8(q8);" class="col-md-2 col-12 btn btn-dark border rounded" id="q8-sub" type="submit" value="Check"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Starting of the harder questions -->
    <div id="main-hard-con" class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="overly-behind" class="col-12">
                <p id="text-hard" class="col-12 text-center lead">Now It's time for more personal questions and also harder</p>
                <p id="start2" class="btn-link lead" onclick="start_hard();">Start</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--1h-->
    <div class="container-fluid" id="conh1">
        <div clss="row">
            <div id="overly-behind" class="col-12">
                <form action="#" class="col-12" onsubmit="return false;">
                    <label class="col-12 d-block" for="qh1">What is the name of my best friend?</label>
                    <input class="col-md-3 col-12 border edit rounded mb-2" type="text" id="qh1" placeholder="Type it here"/>
                    <input onclick="questionh1(qh1);" class="col-md-2 col-12 btn btn-dark border rounded" id="qh1-sub" type="submit" value="Check"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--2h-->
    <div class="container-fluid" id="conh2">
        <div clss="row">
            <div id="overly-behind" class="col-12">
                <form action="#" class="col-12" onsubmit="return false;">
                    <label class="col-12 d-block" for="qh2">Where is my پاتوق in Shiraz?<br/>
                        <span dir="rtl"><small>1.عفیف آباد&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2.ارم&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;3.قدوسی&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;4.چمران&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</small></span>
                    </label>
                    <input class="col-md-3 col-12 border edit rounded mb-2" type="text" id="qh2" placeholder="Type it here"/>
                    <input onclick="questionh2(qh2);" class="col-md-2 col-12 btn btn-dark border rounded" id="qh2-sub" type="submit" value="Check"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--3h-->
    <div class="container-fluid" id="conh3">
        <div clss="row">
            <div id="overly-behind" class="col-12">
                <form action="#" class="col-12" onsubmit="return false;">
                    <label class="col-12 d-block" for="qh3">What and where is my favorite cafe in Shiraz?<br/>
                        <span dir="rtl"><small>1.پاپریکا-معالی آباد&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2.بالکافه-ستارخان&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;3.بالکافه-خاکشناسی&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;4.تو همه جا میری بدبخت&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</small></span>
                    </label>
                    <input class="col-md-3 col-12 border edit rounded mb-2" type="text" id="qh3" placeholder="Type it here"/>
                    <input onclick="questionh3(qh3);" class="col-md-2 col-12 btn btn-dark border rounded" id="qh3-sub" type="submit" value="Check"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--4h-->
    <div class="container-fluid" id="conh4">
        <div clss="row">
            <div id="overly-behind" class="col-12">
                <form action="#" class="col-12" onsubmit="return false;">
                    <label class="col-12 d-block" for="qh4">Where is my favorite street in Shiraz?<br/>
                        <span dir="rtl"><small>1.ملاصدرا&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2.زرگری&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;3.خلبانان&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;4.محلاتی&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</small></span>
                    </label>
                    <input class="col-md-3 col-12 border edit rounded mb-2" type="text" id="qh4" placeholder="Type it here"/>
                    <input onclick="questionh4(qh4);" class="col-md-2 col-12 btn btn-dark border rounded" id="qh4-sub" type="submit" value="Check"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--5h-->
    <div class="container-fluid" id="conh5">
        <div clss="row">
            <div id="overly-behind" class="col-12">
                <form action="#" class="col-12" onsubmit="return false;">
                    <label class="col-12 d-block" for="qh5">How is Ali Bolouki in his mind?<br/>
                        <span><small>1. A person that consider everything important<br/> 2. A person who wants to just see and make everybody and himself happy<br/>3. A wild person<br/>4. A selfish person</small></span>
                    </label>
                    <input class="col-md-3 col-12 border edit rounded mb-2" type="text" id="qh5" placeholder="Type it here"/>
                    <input onclick="questionh5(qh5);" class="col-md-2 col-12 btn btn-dark border rounded" id="qh5-sub" type="submit" value="Check"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--6h-->
    <div class="container-fluid" id="conh6">
        <div clss="row">
            <div id="overly-behind" class="col-12">
                <form action="#" class="col-12" onsubmit="return false;">
                    <label class="col-12 d-block" for="qh6">Do you think I ever had a girlfriend?</label>
                    <input class="col-md-3 col-12 border edit rounded mb-2" type="text" id="qh6" placeholder="Type it here"/>
                    <input onclick="questionh6(qh6);" class="col-md-2 col-12 btn btn-dark border rounded" id="qh6-sub" type="submit" value="Check"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Showing Score-->
    <div id="score-con" class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <p id="score" class="col-12 mt-3">Score: 100</p>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script>
        //Score
        var score = 100;

        // click on start text - hide main-con and block con1
        function start() {
            document.getElementById("main-con").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("con1").style.display = "block";
        }

        // q1
        var q1 = document.getElementById("q1");
        function question1 (q1) {
            if (q1.value === "10/05/1384" || q1.value === "10/5/1384"|| q1.value === "2005/8/1" || q1.value === "2005/08/01") {
                window.alert("That's right. I'm close to 16");
                document.getElementById("con1").style.display = "none";
                //showing question 2
                document.getElementById("con2").style.display = "block";
            } else {
                window.alert("No that's not right. Make sure to use the correct form of date like 05/02/1373 or 2002/05/12");
                score -= 5;
                document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "Score: " + score;
            }
        }

        //q2
        var q2 = document.getElementById("q2");
        function question2 (q2) {
            if (q2.value === "Shiraz" || q2.value === "shiraz" || q2.value === "شیراز") {
                window.alert("Well that was easy");
                document.getElementById("con2").style.display = "none";
                //showing question 3
                document.getElementById("con3").style.display = "block";
            } else {
                window.alert("Are you sure? Make sure to check the dictation");
                score -= 5;
                document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "Score: " + score;
            }
        }

        //q3
        var q3 = document.getElementById("q3");
        function question3 (q3) {
            if (q3.value === "3") {
                window.alert("Good job");
                document.getElementById("con3").style.display = "none";
                //showing question 4
                document.getElementById("con4").style.display = "block";
            } else {
                window.alert(" Try again (Type the number)");
                score -= 5;
                document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "Score: " + score;
            }
        }

        //q4 
        var q4 = document.getElementById("q4");
        function question4 (q4) {
            if (q4.value === "4") {
                window.alert("Yeah dude I listen to any music that I think it's great");
                document.getElementById("con4").style.display = "none";
                //showing question 5
                document.getElementById("con5").style.display = "block";
            } else {
                window.alert("Yoo dude!!! Think more ");
                score -= 5;
                document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "Score: " + score;
            }
        }

        //q5 
        var q5 = document.getElementById("q5");
        function question5 (q5) {
            if (q5.value === "yes" || q5.value === "Yes") {
                window.alert("I wish I had but I don't. Sometimes a dog can be more helpful than a person");
                score -= 5;
                document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "Score: " + score;
            } else if (q5.value === "no" || q5.value === "No") {
                window.alert("Could you please buy me a dog!?");
                document.getElementById("con5").style.display = "none";
                //showing question 6
                document.getElementById("con6").style.display = "block";
            } else {
                window.alert("Just type yes or no");
            }
        }

        //q6
        var q6 = document.getElementById("q6");
        function question6 (q6) {
            if (q6.value === "yes" || q6.value === "Yes") {
                window.alert("Of course I like motorcycle as much as car");
                document.getElementById("con6").style.display = "none";
                //showing question 7
                document.getElementById("con7").style.display = "block";
            } else if (q6.value === "no" || q6.value === "No") {
                window.alert("Why do you think that?!");
                score -= 5;
                document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "Score: " + score;
            } else {
                window.alert("Type yes or no");
            }
        }
        
        //q7
        var q7 = document.getElementById("q7");
        function question7 (q7) {
            if (q7.value === "1") {
                window.alert("Yes I really like BMW's cars");
                document.getElementById("con7").style.display = "none";
                //showing question 8
                document.getElementById("con8").style.display = "block";
            } else {
                window.alert("Naaah! Which one is more moderne? (Write the number)");
                score -= 5;
                document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "Score: " + score;
            }
        }

        //q8
        var q8 = document.getElementById("q8");
        function question8 (q8) {
            if (q8.value === "3") {
                window.alert("You got it!");
                document.getElementById("con8").style.display = "none";
                //showing haed questions
                document.getElementById("main-hard-con").style.display = "block";
            } else {
                window.alert("No think better");
                score -= 5;
                document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "Score: " + score;
            }
            startHQ();
        }



        //Hard question function
        function startHQ() {
            if (score >= 70) {
                function start_hard() {
                document.getElementById("main-hard-con").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("conh1").style.display = "block";
                }

                //qh1 
                var qh1 = document.getElementById("qh1");
                function questionh1 (qh1) {
                    if (qh1.value === "Mahan" || qh1.value === "mahan" || qh1.value === "ماهان") {
                        window.alert("Oh my God! Did you know that? That's right");
                        document.getElementById("conh1").style.display = "none";
                        //Showing question 2
                        document.getElementById("conh2").style.display = "block";
                    } else if (qh1.value === "Saba" || qh1.value === "saba" || qh1.value === "صبا" || qh1.value === "Sweetheart" || qh1.value === "sweetheart") {
                        window.alert("I really like to be your best friend but you said that we may can't be by now");
                    } else {
                        window.alert("No that's wrong (He is a boy)");
                    }
                }

                //qh2
                var qh2 = document.getElementById("qh2");
                function questionh2 (qh2) {
                    if (qh2.value === "2") {
                        window.alert("هااااع باریکلا");
                        document.getElementById("conh2").style.display = "none";
                        //Showing question 3
                        document.getElementById("conh3").style.display = "block";
                    } else if (qh2.value === "1") {
                        window.alert("اره قبلا اونجا ولو بودم");
                    } else {
                        window.alert("Think more (Type the number)");
                    }
                }

                //qh3
                var qh3 = document.getElementById("qh3");
                function questionh3 (qh3) {
                    if (qh3.value === "4") {
                        window.alert("هااا والا همه جا");
                        document.getElementById("conh3").style.display = "none";
                        //Showing question 4
                        document.getElementById("conh4").style.display = "block";
                    } else if (qh3.value === "3") {
                        window.alert("دوست دارم همیشه اونجا باشم ولی خب نمیشه");
                    } else {
                        window.alert("بزن همه جا بره پی کارشا");
                    }
                }

                //qh4
                var qh4 = document.getElementById("qh4");
                function questionh4 (qh4) {
                    if (qh4.value === "2") {
                        window.alert("(¬‿¬)Yeah!");
                        document.getElementById("conh4").style.display = "none";
                        //Showing question 5
                        document.getElementById("conh5").style.display = "block";
                    } else {
                        window.alert("Try again!(*/ω＼*)");
                    }
                }

                //qh5
                var qh5 = document.getElementById("qh5");
                function questionh5 (qh5) {
                    if (qh5.value === "2") {
                        window.alert("Yes when I see the person who I like is happy, I will be happy x 10");
                        document.getElementById("conh5").style.display = "none";
                        //Showing question 6
                        document.getElementById("conh6").style.display = "block";
                    } else {
                        window.alert("Not true");
                    }
                }

                //qh6
                var qh6 = document.getElementById("qh6");
                function questionh6 (qh6) {
                    if (qh6.value === "yes" || qh6.value === "Yes") {
                        window.alert("Jesus Christ! \nI don't know why everyone thinks that I should've had a girlfriend. Look I swear to GOD I didn't have any.\nIf you want to know why I didn't have, you can ask me in privet");
                        document.getElementById("conh6").style.display = "none";
                        //Showing question 7
                        // document.getElementById("conh7").style.display = "block";
                    } else if (qh6.value === "no" || qh6.value === "No") {
                        window.alert("Yeah I didn't ever had one. However, everybody thinks that I'm lying\n They say you look suspicious");
                    }
                }
            //If the score is less than 70
            } else {
                document.getElementById("text-hard").innerHTML = "Well your score is less than 70, so you can't continue but you can try again by refreshing the page";
                document.getElementById("start2").style.display = "none";
            }
        }
     </script>
    
    <!--Bootstrap4-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+YQ4JLhjyBLPDQt//I+STsc9iw4uQqACwlvpslubQzn4u2UU2UFM80nGisd026JF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the problem? What do you expect to happen? What actually happens? How exactly do you reproduce the behaviour?

Comment: Is there an error or anything? Given that you are passing in the element, you could move them out of `startHQ` if you wanted.

Comment: Look I asked user some questions before and I gave  user a score.
An now if the score is more than 70, another questions should show up one by one.
everything is working unless the little functions into the big function.

Comment: I think you need not to wrap your code in `startHQ` . Simply write your code outside the function. Also if you see you are calling `quesion1` with argument `qh`, which is not required and is wrong as well. You are evaluating qh before function execution.

Comment: I have a button that when user click on it, the questions should show up one by one.
The problem is when I click on the button nothing will happed.
The button has "onclick="start_hard()";

Comment: The "else" work right but the "if" does not.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the functions outside and only call them from inside like so

```js
function questionh1(qh1) {
  if (qh1.value === "Mahan" || qh1.value === "mahan" || qh1.value === "m") {
    window.alert("Oh my God! Did you know that? That's right");
    document.getElementById("conh1").style.display = "none";
    //Showing question 2
    document.getElementById("conh2").style.display = "block";
  } else if (qh1.value === "spri" || qh1.value === "spio" || qh1.value === "swi" || qh1.value === "Sweetheart" || qh1.value === "sweetheart") {
    window.alert("I really like to be your best friend but you said that we may can't be by now");
  } else {
    window.alert("No that's wrong (He is a boy)");
  }
}

function questionh2(qh2) {
  if (qh2.value === "2") {
    window.alert("yeah");
    document.getElementById("conh2").style.display = "none";
    //Showing question 3
    document.getElementById("conh3").style.display = "block";
  } else if (qh2.value === "1") {
    window.alert("No way!");
  } else {
    window.alert("Think more (Type the number)");
  }
}

function startHQ() {
  if (score >= 70) {
    function start_hard() {
      document.getElementById("main-hard-con").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("conh1").style.display = "block";
    }

    //qh1 
    var qh1 = document.getElementById("qh1");
    questionh1("qh1")


    //qh2
    var qh2 = document.getElementById("qh2");
    questionh2("qh2")
    // There is more questions
    // .
    // .
    // .
    // .
    // .
    // .
    // .
    //If the score is less than 70
  } else {
    document.getElementById("text-hard").innerHTML = "Well your score is less than 70, so you can't continue but you can try again by refreshing the page";
    document.getElementById("start2").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<!--1h-->
<div class="container-fluid" id="conh1">
  <div clss="row">
    <div id="overly-behind" class="col-12">
      <form action="#" class="col-12" onsubmit="return false;">
        <label class="col-12 d-block" for="qh1">What is the name of my best friend?</label>
        <input class="col-md-3 col-12 border edit rounded mb-2" type="text" id="qh1" placeholder="Type it here" />
        <input onclick="questionh1(qh1);" class="col-md-2 col-12 btn btn-dark border rounded" id="qh1-sub" type="submit" value="Check" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--2h-->
<div class="container-fluid" id="conh2">
  <div clss="row">
    <div id="overly-behind" class="col-12">
      <form action="#" class="col-12" onsubmit="return false;">
        <label class="col-12 d-block" for="qh2">Where is my پاتوق in Shiraz?<br/>
                        <span dir="rtl"><small>1.عفیف آباد&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2.ارم&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;3.قدوسی&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;4.چمران&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</small></span>
                    </label>
        <input class="col-md-3 col-12 border edit rounded mb-2" type="text" id="qh2" placeholder="Type it here" />
        <input onclick="questionh2(qh2);" class="col-md-2 col-12 btn btn-dark border rounded" id="qh2-sub" type="submit" value="Check" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```